# Compile error - Return value must be of type : List

Tags: lightning-aura-components, class, aggregate

I have the above error from this controller, I have very similar one but it doesn't give any compile error. the constructor and the controller is below

```
public class Wk_TraineePerformanceAuraController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c> getTraineeProgress(){
        //Get looged in user details
        User loggedInUser = [SELECT Id,
                             ContactId,
                             Contact.AccountId,
                             Contact.Company_Contact__c
                             FROM User
                             WHERE ID=: UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('=loggedInUser===='+loggedInUser);

        List<AggregateResult> agrResults=
            [Select 
             Sum(Achieved_Credits_to_Rpting_Yr_End__c) achivedCredit,
             Sum(PC_Credits_Total__c) pcCredit,
             Sum(Programme_Credits__c) progCredits
             FROM  Funding_Cycles_TA__c 
             WHERE Enrolled_in_Rpting_Yr__c=True  
             AND (Training_Agreement__r.Funding_Source__c ='IT - Industry Training' 
                  OR Training_Agreement__r.Funding_Source__c ='UF - Un-funded')
             AND Reporting_Year__c =THIS_YEAR
             AND  (Training_Agreement__r.Company_Id__c = : loggedInUser.contact.AccountId OR
                   Training_Agreement__r.Parent_Company_ID_for_Community__c = : loggedInUser.contact.AccountId)
             GROUP by Training_Agreement__r.Company_Id__c];

        List<Wk_PerformanceQueryResults> aqResults = new List<Wk_PerformanceQueryResults>(); 
        for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults){
            aqResults.add(new Wk_PerformanceQueryResults(ar));  
        }
        if (loggedInUser.Contact.Company_Contact__c == TRUE)   {
            return aqResults;
        }  else return NULL;
    }
}

global class Wk_PerformanceQueryResults {
    @AuraEnabled
    Public Decimal AchievedCredits {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Public Decimal PCCredits {get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    Public Decimal ProgramCredits {get; set;}

    //Constructor
    global Wk_PerformanceQueryResults(AggregateResult ar){
        AchievedCredits = (Decimal)ar.get('achivedCredit');
        PCCredits = (Decimal)ar.get('pcCredit');
        ProgramCredits =(Decimal)ar.get('progCredits');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method declares that it returns `List<Funding_Cycles_TA__c>`, but you're actually returning a `List<Wk_PerformanceQueryResults>`. You'll want to change your return type to match.

Comment: @JayWeera Yeah, we all make silly mistakes now and again. Glad I could help!